# PouchDB dump on a mobile device

Tags: couchdb, database-replication, dump, pouchdb

I set an application with several mobile devices synchronizing their pouch db with a couchdb. Data is only synchronized from the couchdb to the pouchdb.
In case of unexpected behavior I want to introduce an option to create a dump of the pouchdb instance of a user.
I saw the option of to dump the entire pouchDB per replication to the couchDB. In this case I had to made sure to create a new database, as I do not want the pouchdb to replicate in the existing tables, as the synchronization is designed to work only from couch to pouch.
Is there an other option to create dump on a mobile device?